# nuxt.jsで画像が404だったときにerrorイベントが呼ばれない。

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

YouTubeのサムネイルで高解像度のものが404だった場合に低解像度のURLに切り替えたいと考え以下のオープンソースを使って実装しようと考えましたが、どうやら404のときにerrorイベントが呼ばれていないようです。(これはimgタグに`@error="method"`を入れることで確かめました。)

https://github.com/Dpblandin/vue-image-fallback

どのようにすれば404を検知して画像を差し替えることができるのでしょうか。